# Xen HVM Windows 2008 network bridge

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, virtualization, xen, bridge

I have a problem with the `Windows Server 2008` guest (hvm). I can't get a network interface running for him.

I also have a `Debian guest` and it's working ok, but I can't do it with the `Win2k8 guest`. When I started the VM, the machine freezes and I can't connect by ssh to the host.

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 188.165.B.C
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 188.165.B.0
        broadcast 188.165.255.255
        gateway 188.165.B.254
```

**brctl show**

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
eth0        8000.e840f20acc28   no      peth0
```

**/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp**

```
...
(vif-script vif-bridge)
(network-script 'network-bridge') 
...
```

**/etc/xen/win2k8.cfg**

```
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=5.39.F.G,mac=yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy,type=ioemu,bridge=eth0' ]
```

**/etc/xen/debian.cfg**

```
#  Networking
#
vif         = [ 'ip=178.33.D.E,mac=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx' ]
```

As you can see, in the `Debian guest` I only have to specify an IP address and a MAC. But if I put that in the `Win2k8 guest`, the machine does not start.

I am using Xen 4.0

Comment: I finally fixed it by creating a "manual" bridge in /etc/network/interfaces instead of let XEN to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised to see "peth0" in your btctl show output. Perhaps your issue is a simple typo? (but then no idea how your Debian VM should work)

And in my only Debian based system I have right now with a bridge (A proxmox 2.1 machine), I also have the bridge in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# cat /etc/network/interfaces
[...]
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth1 inet manual

iface eth2 inet manual

iface eth3 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address  10.11.12.13
    netmask  255.255.0.0
    gateway  10.11.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
[...]


# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vmbr0           8000.0025903b7d66       no              eth0
                                                        eth1
                                                        eth2
                                                        eth3
                                                        tap100i0
```

Comment: peth0 is created by default by Xen. My /etc/network/interfaces does not have a bridge created, as you can see. It is being created by xen when a VM is created

Comment: And with Debian guest everything works fine. It's just with HVM Win2k8. I don't know why but it does not create a right bridged interface

Comment: Just one more thing, eth1, eth2 and eth3 are for failover ips? Because I have it for that, but I do not add them to the bridge

Comment: My system is strange and explaining it would be out of context... but here it is. My system is just in the experimental stage. When finished this is what I will do: eth0 is broken (60% packet loss for no reason). eth1, 2, and 3 will be separate networks, and eth4 is the SAN NIC. If eth1 breaks too (also on motherboard), then eth5 (10Gbps) will replace eth1 (1Gbps). I wouldn't use a bridge as a failover; it probably wouldn't work. I would use link aggregation for failover.